# return type for deployments list using Kubernetes go client

Tags: go, kubernetes-go-client

```
    package main

    import (
          "fmt"
        "html/template"
        "net/http"
        "os"
        log "github.com/kubernetes/klog"
        "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
        "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
        "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    )


    type NamespaceDetails struct { //namespace details struct
        Namespace []string
    }


    var templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("./*.html"))         
    var microservice = "/microservice/"
    var detailed_view = "/detailed/"
    var kube_config_path = os.Getenv("HOME")+"/.kube/config"
    var config, _ = clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kube_config_path)
    var clientset,_ = kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)                              
   var NamespaceClient, _ = clientset.CoreV1().Namespaces().List(v1.ListOptions{}) 

    func main() {
        http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css"))))
        http.Handle("/jpeg/", http.StripPrefix("/jpeg/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css"))))
        http.HandleFunc("/", Homepage)             // calling homepage function at '/' url
        http.HandleFunc(microservice, Deployments) //calling Deployments function at '/microserivce/' url
        http.HandleFunc(detailed_view, DetailedView)
        // http.HandleFunc("/onlyme", onlyme)
        http.ListenAndServe(":8801", nil) // server runs at this port
    }


    func Homepage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        NamespaceStruct := NamespaceDetails{}
        for _, Namespaces := range NamespaceClient.Items {
            log.V(5).Info("inside namespace items loop in homepage")
            NamespaceStruct.Namespace = append(NamespaceStruct.Namespace, Namespaces.Name)
        }
                templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "homepage2.html", NamespaceStruct)
    }

    func deployments(namespace string)(*"k8s.io/api/apps/v1".DeploymentList, error){
        return  clientset.AppsV1().Deployments(namespace).List(v1.ListOptions{})
    }
```

when i am trying to run this code it is giving error:

> syntax error: unexpected literal "k8s.io/api/apps/v1", expecting type

i want to return deploymentslist using deploymnets function.i dont know what return type to use so that i succesfully return deployments list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is invalid syntax:

```
func deployments(namespace string)(*"k8s.io/api/apps/v1".DeploymentList, error){
```

This is the right syntax:

```
func deployments(namespace string)(*v1.DeploymentList, error){
```

However, you already have another `v1` package imported, so you have to import that package with a different alias, and use that name,

Comment: its giving this error ,undefined: "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1".DeploymentList

Comment: i imported apps/v1 package with other name and its working fine

Comment: @SaiVamsi, please post your solution as a answer so other community members can take make use of it.

Answer (score 2):

in imports add this line

```
v2 "k8s.io/api/apps/v1"
```

and update the function parameter as following

```
func deployments(namespace string)(*v2.DeploymentList, error){
```

incase if u r looking for podslist/namespacelist

```
import  v3 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
```

and update function as,

```
 func func_name (input paramteters)(*v3.NamespaceList/PodList , error){
```